# Validate string to have no space char and only first and last char as delimeter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need validation for string to comply with next:

- no space char
- starts with one delimiter char
- ends with one delimiter char
- has no other char as delimiter char

How this can be done?

**Updated** sorry missed that should only be one delimiter char at start and at the end

Comment: +1 for regex. Learn it right now, it's a 'must have' skill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, this should do:

```
char delimiter = ...  
string delimiterString = delimiter.ToString();
string s = ...
bool right = !s.Contains(' ') 
  && s.StartsWith(delimiterString) 
  && s.EndsWith(delimiterString)
  && !s.Substring(1,s.Length-2).Contains(delimiter);
```

Comment: looks good, by the way trim will do multiple and add check for null as well

Comment: Now it should work correctly, the null-check is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex...Assuming # as delimeter and zero characrters between as acceptable.

```
Regex rx=new Regex("^#+[^\s]*#$");

return rx.IsMatch(teststring);
```